# Use Google Translate without mouse

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

When I want to translate something i do this:

1. Open browser
2. Write translate into searchbar. This makes the translator come up.
3. Click on the "input text" window
4. write something that should be translated.

It frustrates me that I have to use my mouse to do step 3. Is there a way to avoid doing this?

It's obviously nothing big, but it would save me a couple of seconds now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times until the cursor is in the input field.

If you use `translate.google.com` in step 2, you'll go to the full Google Translate page. There, the cursor starts out in the input field.

Comment: You have to hit tab 23 times to get to the textfield, so not really a feasible solution, but thank you for the translate.google.com tip.